# Get all HardDisk Partitions n a loop in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a loop in PowerShell where I have all drive letters from the partitions of the internal hard drives (no USB, card readers or similar)

I have try someone like this

```
$diskdrive = gwmi win32_diskdrive | ?{$_.interfacetype -eq "IDE" -or $_.interfacetype -eq "SCSI"}
$letters = $diskdrive | %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"} |  %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"} | %{$_. deviceid}
```

My problem is, I don't know if I can find all of them with IDE and SCSI and how to get a loop of $letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WMI cmdlets are deprecated and should be replaced with CIM where possible. If you just want the fixed disks drive letters, this will achieve the result.

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_logicaldisk |
    Where-Object drivetype -eq 3 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DeviceID
```

Name can be substituted for deviceid, my testing shows they are the same value.

You can also target multiple machines directly

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_logicaldisk -CimSession Computer1,Computer2,Computer3 |
    Where-Object drivetype -eq 3 | Select-Object @{n="Computer";e={$_.pscomputername}},@{n="Drive Letters";e={$_.deviceid}}
```

Here's a listing of the different drivetypes
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.drivetype?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Great. Thank you